# Razor view not seeing all of the public members of an assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am experiencing a very unusual problem. I added a reference DLL to my MVC project. A DLL I built. Everything worked fine. I modified the DLL. Everything still worked fine. Let's say at this point the DLL assembly has 10 members and that these members can be accessed from anywhere in the MVC project. I then added 3 new members to the assembly and rebuilt it. When I use the assembly from a controller, I can see all of the members (including the new ones). However, when I use the assembly from a Razor view, the previously defined members are there but the 3 new members are not. I have checked the date on the DLL, I can see all of the members using the Object Browser and I have modified the web.config file to add the namespace to the Razor web page. It is acting like the Razor view is stuck looking at a cached copy of the assembly while the rest of the project can see exactly what is supplosed to be there. Please note that I can see the previously defined members from the Razor view so as far as the configuration options go I believe that everything is as it is supposed to be. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

I have opened and closed the project. I have also rebooted the computer. Still have the problem.

Comment: Is it just that the new members aren't showing up in Razor's IntelliSense, or are they completely inaccessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have added the reference to the dll or added the dll to your /bin, rebuild your web app project that contains the views. I find i have to do this be able to get intellisense in VS for dlls. As an example when i added a reference for the Linkshare helper, I had to rebuild the project for it to appear in intellisens ina razor view. See if that works.

Comment: To answer Chris first, it wasn't just an intelliSense issue. Referencing the missing items directly and then trying to run did not work. However, rebuilding the MVC app seems to have done the trick. Apparently not all intellisense/functionality is created equal. Thanks for your responses.